# Authenticating MSSQL through django-pyodbc using Windows Authentication from IIS7

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, django, iis

I'm working on building the intranet for my employer, and I've decided to try getting a django server setup. We use a windows server with MSSQL 2008 containing the bulk of our data. I'm looking to integrate the intranet with both the domain for authentication and the existing MSSQL server.

Everything seems to be working up to the connection with the MSSQL server. The issue seems simple enough: it is trying to use the wrong credentials. I have IIS set up to use windows authentication and disabled the Anonymous login. When I go to the website, I am prompted to enter my credentials. When the page tries to load, django throws an error with the exception:

```
Exception Type: Error
Exception Value: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\\DJANGO$'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
Exception Location: c:\python35\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py in get_new_connection, line 301
```

Note that DJANGO is the name of the virtual computer I'm using to test this server. It seems the solution is as simple as figuring out how to pass the windows login credentials from IIS through django for the initial MSSQL connection.

Now for some details, I have:

- IIS 7.5 running on a windows 7 Professional virtual machine for initial development
- python 3.5.1
- django 1.9.6
- [wfastcgi 2.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wfastcgi)
- [django-pyodbc-azure 1.9.3.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pyodbc-azure)

I have the django settings.py entry:

```
...
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
  ...
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.PersistentRemoteUserMiddelware',
  ...
]
...
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'intranet.wsgi.application' #intranet is the project name
...
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'DatabaseName',
    'HOST': 'Server',
    'AUTOCOMMIT': False,
  }
}
...
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
  'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
]
...
```

I have the interaction between IIS and django working based on the tutorial from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wfastcgi, with the WSIG_HANDLER changed by the suggestion of [Django on IIS: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840354/django-on-iis-django-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-ye) (change prompted because intranet did not have a module named wsgi_app(), not sure how I came to the idea to try it, but it worked and I moved on).

It has taken much effort to get this far, hopefully this is an easy fix. My other thought was to abandon the django sql model system and deal with direct queries, but I'd rather do it the 'right' way before I redevelop the wheel.

Comment: What version of Python? What version of Django? What version of sql_server.pyodbc? The only docs on pyodbc I could find appear to be using the *old* Django DATABASE_* settings.py values. A newer Django and an older DB driver is sure to lead to tears.

Comment: @PeterRowell Python is 3.5.1, Django is 1.9.6, sql_server.pyodbc comes from django-pyodbc-azure 1.9.3.0. Use the link provided in the question for docs on the pyodbc I'm using. Your comment is well made though, I've had to do many battles with different versions of various things. This pyodbc specifically indicates it works with django 1.9.3, not 1.9.6 (a detail I had overlooked until just now)...could that really be all?

Comment: Sorry, missed the link in your question. I doubt the minor version mismatch is causing the problem. I do note that you are not providing `USER` and `PASSWORD` in the DATABASE dict; that could definitely cause this problem.

Comment: @PeterRowell my understanding is that by not supplying the USER and PASSWORD it would use windows authentication. Perhaps there is a 'Trusted_Connection' equivalent option I need to pass? It seems meaningful that it is passing a username/password, it is just using the wrong one...

Comment: Also, I tried adding 'OPTIONS': {'extra_params': "Trusted_Connection=True"} to the DATABASES block in settings.py, but it did not change the error.

Comment: This seems to be a common problem. Has anyone found a solution? We've switched from Apache to IIS, but still run into the same issue mentioned by the OP here.

Comment: @DaveBoltman It has been some time since I've worked on this. Ultimately I decided to drop django and go with ASP.NET. I recall having battles with double-hop authentication because my IIS and SQL were on different machines. I haven't worked on this for over a year though, so I'm afraid I will not be any help :/

Comment: @LuciusSilanus thanks anyways for the reply

Answer (score 2):

We can connect **Django** to **MSSQL(SQL Server)** with **Windows Authentication** using [**mssql-django**](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django).

First, connect to **MSSQL(SQL Server)** with our server name. *I use **SQL Server 2019 Express**:

[image]

Next, from Databases, click on **"New Database..."**:

[image]

Then, put **"test"** to **"Database name:"**, then click on **"OK"**:

[image]

Then, **"test" database** is created:

[image]

Next, from **Server name**, click on **"Properties"**:

[image]

Then, from **"Security"**, we can check that **"Server authentication"** is **"Windows Authentication mode"** set by default. Actually, we can connect **Django** to **MSSQL** with **"Windows Authentication mode"**:

[image]

And, we can also connect **Django** to **MSSQL** with **"SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"** so both modes are fine to connect **Django** to **MSSQL** with **Windows Authentication**:

[image]

Next, set the code below to **"settings.py"** to connect **Django** to **MSSQL** with **Windows Authentication**. This code below is the example of **Django** and **MSSQL** in **the same Windows Computer(localhost)** and **"ENGINE"** must be **"mssql"** and **"NAME"** is for **Database name "test"** and **"DESKTOP-QVRCPTA"** for **"HOST"** is **Windows Computer Name(Device name)**. *Keep it blank for **"PORT"** because there will be error if setting any port number e.g. **"2244"**, **"9877"** or even **"1433"** which is **the default port number of MSSQL**:

```py
# "settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'mssql',                    # Must be "mssql"
        'NAME':'test',                       # DB name
        'HOST':'DESKTOP-QVRCPTA\SQLEXPRESS', # <server>\<instance>
        'PORT':'',                           
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

In addition, **"DESKTOP-QVRCPTA"** can be replaced with **"localhost"** and **"USER"** and **"PASSWORD"** can be put with **empty string** and **"PORT"** can be removed as shown below to connect **Django** to **MSSQL** with **Windows Authentication**:

```py
# "settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'mssql',
        'NAME':'test',
        'USER':'',                     # Here
        'PASSWORD':'',                 # Here
        'HOST':'localhost\SQLEXPRESS', # Here
        # 'PORT':'',                   # Here      
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

Next, install **the latest package [mssql-django](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django)**:

```
pip install mssql-django
```

Then, make migrations and migrate:

```
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```

Then, create superuser:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Now, we could connect **Django** to **MSSQL** with **Windows Authentication**, then create the tables for **"test" database**. ***the default schema "dbo"** is put before the table names as shown below:

[image]

And, this is **Django Admin**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit late for anyone trying to run around the Django fun with try the following it worked for me:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'NAME': 'my_database',
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'HOST': 'dbserver',
    'PORT': 'XXXX',
    'OPTIONS': { 'DRIVER':'SQL Server Native Client 11.0', 'Extra_Params':'Trusted_Connection=True'},
}}
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem and saved me [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62387839/12274302) tutorial

For Django App just change  connection to below code and work perfect with Identity= Localsystem

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
        "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=MyServerName;Database=MyDbName; uid=MyUsernameLoginDb; pwd=MyDbPasswordLoginToDB; ")
```